# SQL - Check if employee FirstName and/or LastName exists

Tags: sql

Given below tables, check if either columns in Table 1 exists in Table 2 -

Table_1:

| FULL_NAME |
| --- |
| Crystal, Crystal |
| Carmen, TEST2 |
| XYZ, ABC |
| BLA, VVV |

Table_2:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Crystal |
| Carmen |
| ZZZ |
| AAA |
| VVV |

Output:

| FULL_NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| Crystal, Crystal | TRUE |
| Carmen, TEST2 | TRUE |
| XYZ, ABC | FALSE |
| BLA, VVV | TRUE |

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @user2330382, do you test my answer bellow. Please, do this and share with us feed-back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` with `instr`:

```
select t1.full_name, exists (select 1 from table_2 t2 where instr(t1.full_name, t2.name) > 0) status from table_1 t1;
```

Output:

| full_name | status |
| --- | --- |
| Crystal, Crystal | 1 |
| Carmen, TEST2 | 1 |
| XYZ, ABC | 0 |
| BLA, VVV | 1 |

Edit: the solution above will match any occurrence of substrings, however, if you want the match to be based solely on the comma separated values, you can use a recursive cte to get the substrings:

```
with recursive vals(id, n) as (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)), t.* from table_1 t),
     cte(id, v, r) as (
         select id, case when instr(n, ", ") > 0 then substr(n, 1, instr(n, ", ")-1) else n end, case when instr(n, ", ") > 0 then substr(n, instr(n, ", ")+2, length(n) - instr(n, ", ")) else "" end from vals
         union all
         select id, case when instr(r, ", ") > 0 then substr(r, 1, instr(r, ", ")-1) else r end, case when instr(r, ", ") > 0 then substr(r, instr(r, ", ")+2, length(r) - instr(r, ", ")-1) else "" end from cte where length(r) > 0
)
select s1.n, s3.c from (select s.id, max(s.v in (select * from table_2)) c from cte s group by s.id) s3 join vals s1 on s3.id = s1.id;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=037865df8192069325c99684ff299efb).

Comment: It would be good if you added an explanation for what each of those functions does for those who don't know.

Comment: Although this works with the sample data, this might not be great depending on how you want to handle non-exact matches. e.g. This will match "Rob" in table2 with "Johnson, Robert" in table1. Or "John" in table2 with "Johnson, Robert" in table1.

Comment: `instr` is not recognized by SQL Server, for example. The question is about SQL in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
--Suported on MSSQL, MSACCESS, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreeSQL
SELECT t1.FULL_NAME,
CASE
    WHEN Temp.CONTAINING IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
    WHEN Temp.CONTAINING IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE'
END AS 'STATUS'

FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT NAME, 
        (SELECT FULL_NAME
            FROM Table_1
            WHERE FULL_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%',NAME,'%')) as 'CONTAINING'
    FROM Table_2) Temp ON
t1.FULL_NAME = Temp.CONTAINING
```

Comment: This uses `+` as the concatenation operation, so it won't work in Oracle (mentioning this since there's a comment that the other answer that it doesn't work on SQL Server). This also has the same issue matching partial names (which may or may not be desired).

Comment: Good note, @EdmCoff. I updated my answer, substituting `+` to `CONCAT()`